# having an error when trying to put more than one marker in google map API

Tags: android-studio

I've tried to put more than one marker in the map put it just the last one becuase the camera take the last postion only

and this is my code

```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(34, 151);
    LatLng saa = new LatLng(-24.77, 46.73);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("sydney"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(saa).title("saa"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(saa));
}
```

//---

when i build the project this error came up 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

could anyone help to solve my problem 
that's my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

}
```